# On-demand Elastic IT Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services

Please help me with my assignment. I just need a brief idea.

Here is the scenario: You are the IT administrator for a large Enterprise. You have transformed your company's IT into a virtual infrastructure that you provision, manage and even provide the backup support. You are also making sure you minimize the cost of this virtual infrastructure that you are providing for your business. You release resources when someone is not using it, but making sure that resources are available (mostly) when needed based on some policy, schedule or active monitoring. In addition, you are providing Elastic infrastructure to set of users who require elasticity support.

Requirements: There are two parts to this assignment. (1) on-demand infrasturcture, (2) Elastic infrastructure.

Part 1: On-demand Infrastructure:
1. Design an on-demand provision and release mechanism as the base service. You shall need ability to snapshot a VM and restore it later on from this snapshot.
2. You need to persist data on a persistent storage.
3. You shall need the ability to detect when machines are idle. This you should do using CloudWatch service.
4. You need to provide some form of static IP to make sure login remains the same.

Part 2: Elastic Service: You may use AWS Auto-scale/ELB or develop your own Elasticity capability. We shall discuss this in the next class.

AWS Auto-scale/ELB: You shall use Autoscale to support Elastic infrastructure for the set of users that need such an support. You can download Autoscale SDK and libraries to configure such a service. It does not need to be integrated with Java code. It could be command line based that you shall set up separately. Please watch the youtube video link I had provided as part of Elasticity lecture.

Your own Elastic code: You may develop your own elasticity code. You could use cloudwatch to perform the monitoring.